# Cable Recommendation, Games Stuck at 30 FPS on External Monitor ! Needs Advice

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, hdmi, displays, display-port

Hello Everyone I hope you are in the best of your health in this pandemic. I recently bought a gaming monitor for my work as well as for the little gaming that I do. I have connected my laptop to my monitor using an HDMI cable. Now the problem that I am facing is in most of the games I am just getting 30 FPS. I have a 1050 TI 4GB graphic memory so I doubt that it produces only 30 FPS because clearly when I play on my laptop I get over 90 FPS in Valorant. So my question here is what could be the possible reasons for this ? I did some research and found out the following reasons :

- I am using an old HDMI cable that is not able to transmit more than 30 Hz and indeed I am using an old HDMI cable because the monitor came with a display port and my laptop only has a mini display port.
- My laptop is not able to produce more than 30 FPS on the external monitor.(I highly doubt this could be the reason)

Can someone tell me that If I purchase a mini-display port to display port will that fix the issue or do I have to do some more analysis of the situation here ?

Your responses would are appreciated please can someone help me on this ? I am giving the links of both the monitor and laptop below if anyone wants extra information.

Link of my Monitor : shorturl.at/iyAD4

Link of my Laptop : shorturl.at/wIKXZ

Comment: If the cable is the issue here, you should also notice the low FPS issue on the Desktop. Check the display refresh rate of your monitor in Windows "Advanced display settings".
If that deviates from the refresh rate your monitor should support (your link doesn't work for me), click on "Display adapter properties" -> "Monitor" and try setting the correct refresh rate there. If that still doesn't work, you'll need a better cable - for which I'd recommend going straight to a mini-DP to DP cable.

Comment: My monitor has a feature by which I can see the fps on any application and while I am on a monitor I constantly see 120 FPS but as soon as I open a game like valorant it goes to 30. My monitor supports 165Hz but I am not expecting 165 Hz as I don't think my laptops GPU can produce that !! I will also try the display port and see if that makes any improvement.

Comment: Alright, so you're limited by the HDMI cable to 120 FPS (a Mini-DP to DP cable will fix that and give you the full 165). Your low FPS inside the game might be an energy saving feature in the game or in your graphics driver.

Comment: How can I be completely sure about that ? do I need to check some settings in Nvidia GeForce ? @towe

Comment: I'd start by checking some other game. It might be that the game you're trying to use has some limitations that depend on resolution, GPU, CPU, memory or something else. If you can run the desktop at some specific frequency (e.g. 120 Hz native resolution) the fact that some game runs locked 30 fps is not because of your display cable. However, if you run desktop 120 Hz native resolution 24 bit, cable quality could prevent you from running games 120 Hz HDR which requires 30 bit data transfer and higher quality cable.

Comment: Apparently you're not alone with Valorant 30 FPS issues: https://www.reddit.com/r/VALORANT/comments/fxt244/fps_stuck_at_30_please_help/
I too would recommend trying another game first.

Comment: It appears the links no longer work. could you provide full size links, including names in case the site goes offline.

Comment: Laptop is Asus Rog Strix Gl503GE and monitor is Acer Nitro 165Hz Vg model

Comment: There seems to be a *huge* amount of confusion in this comment thread regarding game render rate, measured in FPS [frames per second] & refresh rate of the display itself [measured in Hz]. The two are not *in the slightest comparable*. It is quite possible to have a game running at 120 fps on a screen only capable of 30Hz [though a waste of time]. If you are running a game which can run 120 fps on the internal display but only 30fps on an external, you must assume there is a rendering difference. Is the external display the same resolution as the internal? If not, you need to factor that in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Options.

For one, the monitor you mention in the coments seems to be a 1440p monitor. This means that a game takes more power to run. Along with the limited amount of ram it's very well possible that this is normal behaviour. One test would be to reduce the resolution to 1920*1080 in the game and see if that increases framerate to what is expected.

One option would be to check if the refresh rate of the monitor is stuck on 30hz,
On windows 10 you can do this by checking the following location

Setting > System > Display > Advanced Display Settings > Display Adapter Properties.
In the monitors tab you can see the active refresh rate. If it's stuck on 30Hz, this is where you can update it.

Second, would be to see if Vertical synchronisation is on, either in the game or in the Nvidia graphics settings. To keep things synchronised it usually limits the framerate to the highest standard refresh rate(so usually 30 or 60hz, it might be that the 90hz that you experience on your laptop is also one of these standards)

Lastly I would make sure to check other games and see if this is a single game issue. If not. it would be time to use monitoring tools like HWMonitor or MSIAfterburner to see what is causing the bottlenecks.